# create other models using the last id on django admin save

Tags: django, django-admin

I have two models: House & Rooms

I have a custom form for Houses, like this:

```
class HouseFormCustom(forms.ModelForm):

    rooms_number = forms.CharField()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        rooms_number = self.cleaned_data.get('rooms_number', None)
        return super(HouseFormCustom, self).save(commit=commit)

    class Meta:
        model = House


class HouseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = HouseFormCustom


admin.site.register(House, HouseAdmin)
```

I want to use rooms_number to save on DB X rooms models based and connected to the last Houses created.

like:

```
for x in range(0, rooms_number):
  r = Room()
  r.house = last_id_house
  r.save()
```

Any hints? I mean, where I should put the last snippet of code?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this:

```
class HouseFormCustom(forms.ModelForm):

    rooms_number = forms.IntegerField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = House


class HouseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    form = HouseFormCustom

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.save()

        rooms_number = request.POST.get('rooms_number', None)

        if(rooms_number):
            Room.objects.bulk_create([Room(house=obj) for x in range(0, rooms_number)])


admin.site.register(House, HouseAdmin)
```